# Why does the HTTP standard not feature a "message size" at the beginning of each message?

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm trying to write a simple HTTP parser and it seems like it's being complicated by the fact there is not simple "byte count" at the beginning of each message. Instead, you need to parse through header information, check to see if there is a "Content-Length" header key and then parse for two CR/LFs before reading the message contents.

So my question: why would the HTTP standard not feature a "byte count" number at the beginning of each message? This seems like it would simplify a lot of parsing code.

Comment: And that’s why HTTP/2 is so much easier to parse!

Comment: I don't have a good answer as to 'why', but people like text-based protocols and formats and have developed numerous over the years. There's drawbacks and benefits. HTTP/2 is a binary serialization of HTTP which *will* do this.

Answer (score 0):

Because you might not know at the time when you start sending the response.